# Choosing/Learning new Type Libraries to reference in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have done a fair bit of Automation programming using Access to drive the operations of other Office programs. This has been straightforward because the references needed are specific Microsoft programs and I get help learning the type libraries from the Developer Reference Help pages and exploring the classes, methods, and properties in the object browser.

I've also used type libraries from Lotus Notes and Adobe Acrobat to integrate specific functions of those programs, but I needed to use SDKs to understand those objects and methods.

Now I'm looking to automate a web browser control in future projects. I can find specific code samples if I search very specific topics, like `[vba] http post web form`, but what I'm really looking for is a higher-level review of type libraries and active-X controls. I've found snippets of code using `SHDocVw` and `MSHTML`, but I am looking for some guidance on which type libraries to use in this area and how to explore other possibilities.

Comment: In Access 2010 there is a webbrowser control. I think it's just a wrapper for an activeX - and it works quite well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the Web Browser control in Access 2010, which I believe uses the Microsoft Internet controls reference.

Please see the following screenshot for more information. Note the code changes the zoom of the Web Browser so that an image zooms to fit.

http://screencast.com/t/WsqWTlZRnh

The documentation I found referring to the object used is at the following location:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(v=vs.85).aspx

Good look…